# Emacs elpy : How to view a list of all (global) variables and class attributes in the current buffer?

Tags: python, emacs, elpy

I use `elpy` in `emacs` for Python development. If I enter the command `C-C C-o` I'll be able to view all defined functions, classes and methods in the current buffer. But I don't see any of class attributes and defined (global) variables. Is there any way to have this extra information?

Answer (score 0):

```
globals()
locals()
```

are python commands and will dump the output in the python buffer. you can try extending elpy to make a shortcut dump stuff in a buffer.

Comment: I see. So you confirm that the information is not provided by the current implementation of the elpy as it is.

Comment: elpy is an orphan project and the previous maintainer does not respond to messages. if we do not get a new developer it will die.

Comment: I didn't know that. So what is currently recommended for Emacs users in terms of package(s) as the best option for Python programming?